# How do I add trusted certificate for golang

Tags: ssl, go, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use go get or godep to pull some dependency for my project but I see this in my mac

```
KALEI-M-V11L:election kalei$ dep ensure
The following issues were found in Gopkg.toml:

  ✗ unable to deduce repository and source type for "k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver": unable to read metadata: unable to fetch raw metadata: failed HTTP request to URL "http://k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver?go-get=1": Get https://k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver?go-get=1: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  ✗ unable to deduce repository and source type for "k8s.io/apimachinery": unable to read metadata: unable to fetch raw metadata: failed HTTP request to URL "http://k8s.io/apimachinery?go-get=1": Get https://k8s.io/apimachinery?go-get=1: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  ✗ unable to deduce repository and source type for "k8s.io/client-go": unable to read metadata: unable to fetch raw metadata: failed HTTP request to URL "http://k8s.io/client-go?go-get=1": Get https://k8s.io/client-go?go-get=1: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  ✗ unable to deduce repository and source type for "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime": unable to read metadata: unable to fetch raw metadata: failed HTTP request to URL "http://sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime?go-get=1": Get https://sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime?go-get=1: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  ✗ unable to deduce repository and source type for "k8s.io/code-generator": unable to read metadata: unable to fetch raw metadata: failed HTTP request to URL "http://k8s.io/code-generator?go-get=1": Get https://k8s.io/code-generator?go-get=1: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  ✗ unable to deduce repository and source type for "k8s.io/api": unable to read metadata: unable to fetch raw metadata: failed HTTP request to URL "http://k8s.io/api?go-get=1": Get https://k8s.io/api?go-get=1: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

If I do curl to https://k8s.io/api?go-get=1, it works perfectly so looks like go doesn't trust the cert somehow.

Is there a way to configure it?

Answer (score 4):

According to the go [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/)

> On UNIX systems the environment variables SSL_CERT_FILE and
>   SSL_CERT_DIR can be used to override the system default locations for
>   the SSL certificate file and SSL certificate files directory,
>   respectively.

Sample

```sh
SSL_CERT_FILE=/path/to/x509_encoded_cert_file dep ensure
SSL_CERT_DIR=/path/to/dir/ dep ensure
```